# AngularJS extend model

Tags: angularjs

I had in my old project this bit of code for an API:

```
.factory('Api', ['$resource', 'apiUrl', function ($resource, api) {
    var Api = $resource(api + ':path', {
        path: '@path'
    });

    return Api;
}])
```

and then I had an **Order** model which extended this factory class like this:

```
.factory('Order', ['$filter', 'Api', function ($filter, api) {
    var Order = api;

    angular.extend(Order.prototype, {
        getDescription: function () {
            var rolls = 0,
                cuts = 0,
                skus = [],
                lines = $filter('orderBy')(this.lines, 'sku');

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var line = lines[i];

                switch (line.type) {
                    case 0: // cut
                        cuts++;
                        break;
                    case 1: // roll
                        rolls++
                        break;
                }

                if (skus.indexOf(line.sku) == -1) {
                    skus.push(line.sku);
                }
            }

            var description = '';
            description += cuts > 0 ? cuts > 1 ? cuts + ' x cuts' : cuts + ' x cut' : '';
            description += rolls > 0 && description.length > 0 ? ', ' : '';
            description += rolls > 0 ? rolls > 1 ? rolls + ' x rolls' : rolls + ' x roll' : '';
            description += skus.length == 1 ? ' of ' + skus[0] : '';
            return description;
        },
        getStatus: function () {
            var lines = this.lines,
                status = lines[0].status;

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var line = lines[i];

                if (status !== line.status)
                    return 'Multiple';
            }

            return status;
        },
        getDeliveryDate: function () {
            var lines = this.lines,
                date = lines[0].dates.delivery;

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var line = lines[i];

                if (date !== line.dates.delivery)
                    return 'Multiple';
            }

            date = new Date(date);

            return date;
        },
        getDispatchDate: function () {
            var lines = this.lines,
                date = lines[0].orderDate;

            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var line = lines[i];

                if (date !== lines.orderDate)
                    return 'Multiple';
            }

            date = new Date(date);

            return date;
        }
    });

    return Order;
}]);
```

Now, I have recently changed my API factory to this:

```
// ---
// CONSTANTS.
// ---

.constant('apiUrl', 'http://localhost:54326/')
//.constant('apiUrl', 'http://localhost:81/')

// ---
// SERVICES.
// ---

.service('Api', ['$http', 'HttpHandler', 'apiUrl', function ($http, handler, apiUrl) {

    // Private function to build our request
    var buildRequest = function (url, method, data, params) {
        var model = {
            method: method,
            url: apiUrl + url,
            data: data,
            params: params
        };

        return $http(model);
    }

    // GET
    this.get = function (url, params) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'GET', null, params));
    }

    // POST
    this.post = function (url, data) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'POST', data));
    }

    // PUT
    this.put = function (url, data) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'PUT', data));
    }

    // DELETE
    this.delete = function (url, data) {
        return handler.loadData(buildRequest(url, 'DELETE', data));
    }
}])
```

When I did this, my order model no longer works. I get an error stating:

> > Cannot read property '$$hashKey' of undefined

Is there a way I can get my **Order** model to use the new API factory? Specifically I want to attach functions each object returned by the API.